# Failure of reading registry after opening CFileDialog

Tags: winapi, mfc

Without calling **CFileDialog**, reading a registry seems to work.

But after calling this **CFileDialog** (Even after just opening and closing without calling any file), reading from the registry starts failing.

Here is the **CFileDialog** code:

```
void CprojectTHD_2015_09_28Doc::OnImportFromTextfile()
{
    if(!SaveFile()) return;

    TCHAR szFilter[] = _T("INP Files (*.INP)|*.inp|OUT Files (*.OUT)|*.out||");
    CFileDialog dlg(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST, szFilter);

    CString strPathName;  
    if(IDOK == dlg.DoModal()){
        strPathName = dlg.GetPathName();

        AdPinData *pInputDataTem = new AdPinData();     //to open new input data

        if(pInputDataTem->OpenFile(strPathName)){       //to get Infos from text file
        //to delete the last file Data when it needs a new file
            if(pInputData){ delete pInputData; pInputData=NULL; }
            if(pOutputData){ delete pOutputData; pOutputData=NULL; }
            if(pBusData){ delete pBusData; pBusData=NULL; }

            pInputData = pInputDataTem;
            pInputDataTem = NULL;

            //to open new output data
            pOutputData = new AdPinData();
            pOutputData->initAdPinData(false);  //to just initialize, it doesn't need text file

            //to open new bus data
            pBusData = new AdBusData();
            pBusData->initAdBusData();

            for(int i=1;i<6;i++) MyEnableMenu(true, i); //on all the menu above

            endofTick = 0;                  //set basic value 0
            SignalView::isOverwritten = false;

            UpdateAllViews(NULL);           //to execute Ondraw funcion agian
        }else{
            delete pInputDataTem; pInputDataTem=NULL;
            if(!pInputData) AdPinData::setFlag(false);
        }
    }
}
```

And, here's the code reading from the registry:

```
CString CSerialPort::GetPortName()
{
    DWORD dwcSubKeys, dwcValues, dwcMaxSubKeyName, dwcMaxValueName, dwcMaxValueData;
    TCHAR szBuffer[255] = {0};
    DWORD dwSubKeyIndex = 0;
    DWORD dwValueIndex = 0;
    HKEY hKey = 0;
    LONG lStatus = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    TCHAR szValueName[255] = {0};
    TCHAR szValueData[255] = {0};

    lStatus = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,TEXT("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM"),0,KEY_READ/*KEY_ALL_ACCESS*/,&hKey);

    if (lStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        RegQueryInfoKey(hKey, szBuffer, NULL, 0,
            &dwcSubKeys, &dwcMaxSubKeyName, NULL,
            &dwcValues, &dwcMaxValueName, &dwcMaxValueData,
             NULL, NULL);

        if (dwcValues != 0) {
            do {
                DWORD dwType;   
                DWORD dwcValueName = sizeof(szValueName);
                DWORD dwcValueData = sizeof(szValueData);
                lStatus = RegEnumValue(hKey, dwValueIndex,
                        szValueName, &dwcValueName,
                        NULL, &dwType,
                        (BYTE*)szValueData,
                        &dwcValueData);
                dwValueIndex++;
            } while (lStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS);
        }
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    return szValueData;
}
```

P.S.
I changed the code to this:

```
CString CSerialPort::GetPortName()
{
    DWORD dwcSubKeys,dwcValues,dwcMaxSubKeyName,dwcMaxValueName,dwcMaxValueData;
    dwcSubKeys=dwcValues=dwcMaxSubKeyName=dwcMaxValueName=dwcMaxValueData=0; ///
    DWORD dwSubKeyIndex = 0;
    DWORD dwValueIndex = 0;
    HKEY hKey = 0;
    LONG lStatus = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    TCHAR szValueName[255] = {0};
    TCHAR szValueData[255] = {0};

    lStatus = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,/*TEXT*/_T("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM"),0,KEY_READ,&hKey);

    if (lStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        RegQueryInfoKey(hKey, NULL/*szBuffer*/, NULL, 0,
            &dwcSubKeys, &dwcMaxSubKeyName, NULL,
            &dwcValues, &dwcMaxValueName, &dwcMaxValueData,
             NULL, NULL);

        if (dwcValues != 0) {
            do {
                DWORD dwcValueName = sizeof(szValueName);
                DWORD dwcValueData = sizeof(szValueData);
                lStatus = RegEnumValue(hKey, dwValueIndex,
                        szValueName, &dwcValueName,
                        NULL, NULL, ///
                        (BYTE*)szValueData,
                        &dwcValueData);
                dwValueIndex++;
            } while (lStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS);
        }
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    return szValueData;
}
```

I don't use values which I don't need, and seems it's better than before. At least it's working in any case, but when it's on unplug state (USB), it still gets dwcValues=1, dwcMaxValueName=17, &dwcMaxValueData=10.

Comment: How does it fail exactly ? Use [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) to get more information.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Hi Micahel, there's no error actually. It just fails reading registry with blank "". Before calling CFileDialog, it reads well port registry with "COM2" like this string, but after calling CFileDialog, it starts reading it with blank "".

Comment: I'd start checking the return value of `RegQueryInfoKey`.

Comment: CFileDialog can have a big impact on a program, it loads shell extensions and programmers tend to have a lot of them.  What such an extension could do to make this fail is hard to guess.  Only red flag in the code not using KEY_WOW64_64KEY.  Investigate deeper with SysInternals tools, Process Monitor to verify the registry access and AutoRuns do disable troublesome shell extensions.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for comment. But unfortunately, I don't fully understand. What is "red flag"? and how to investigate with SysInternal tools and i don't get anything in the last sentence..

Comment: So you didn't understand anything I said.  Where do you expect me to begin??  Educate yourself, lots of google search terms in that comment.  Start with "red flag" :)

Comment: @HansPassant Which things do I need to know? :) I mean, I need to finish this project as soon as possible. Will it take many days to study?

Comment: @MichaelWalz No, the registry API returns error codes directly rather than calling `SetLastError`.

Comment: @Sean Since you ignore the return values, how can you say that there is no error. Or did you do some debugging. On the face of it, it would appear that you have this code which you did not write and do not understand, and want us to re-write it for you. Without you having identified the problem yet. Will it take many days to study? One wonders if you want to learn something, or just want somebody to wave a magic wand. Of course it will take time. There are no shortcuts here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes I noticed afterward. Thanks.

Comment: What is in `SaveFile()`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry for late. Well, which one do you mean? to get the return value. It's hard to check on debug mode in the computer which hasn't VS. That's why. In my computer, there never happened any single problem.

Comment: @VladFeinstein I'm sorry for late. There's nothing inside with just some message boxes.

Comment: Use [trace debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_(software)). Don't ignore return values. Don't neglect error checking. Don't be unable to debug.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I changed the code a little, and now it's working better than before. but still it has a small problem. When it's not plugged (I mean USB) it gets a registery value, which is dwcValues=1, dwcMaxValueName=17, dwcMaxValueData=10, and because of this it proceeds next step( It shouldn't go next step in  if (dwcValues != 0) condition )

Comment: This site doesn't work this way. We cannot debug what we cannot see at the bottom of a long trail of comments. If you are really stuck, ask a new question with a really good [mcve].

Comment: @DavidHeffernan okay I'm gonna post a new question. Thank you so much anyway !